# `ProgramFailedToComplete` when I make a transaction

Tags: anchor, cpi, testing

I receive `ProgramFailedToComplete` when I make a CPI:

```
1) vault
Is initialized!:
Error: Raw transaction 3pa2qbGAFNMUbdCXr8nqN43qw9tTzt2ZyFYV3jBAAKN5VpKnOMMMWY4q¿duaUPsUsdtDKsEsgRBLNUGCyk7rFXzb failed ({"err": {"InstructionError": [0,"ProgramFailedToComplete"]}})
at sendAndConfirmRawTransaction
```

This is not a helpful error - how am I supposed to troubleshoot my program with this little level of detail? I'm sure there's something I'm missing. There must be a more specific error that gets thrown somewhere but it's not coming out to the top somehow. I need to know which part of the instruction is causing the problem. Sometimes if I comment out my CPI call it will work. There must be a nested error from in the CPI call but I can't see it.

Comment: Ok, I've now come to the conclusion that it must be something on the typescript test side as I've commented out basically everything from my instruction and the test transaction call still gives the same completely ambiguous error.

Comment: The error is in your first instruction - what is your first instruction? If the first instruction is a CPI, are there logs generated by the program you're CPI-ing to? Maybe run a persistent validator (`solana-test-validator` then `anchor test --skip-local-validator`) and then use `solana logs` to see.

PS I make the question title more useful to help others find it, but I did keep your point that ProgramFailedToComplete is not a helpful error.

Answer (score 2):

You can use sendRawTransaction with skipPreflight set to true to send a transaction even if it fails. This allows you to log the signature and view the transaction in an explorer as shown below. You can view the transaction logs in an explorer and get much more info this way.

```
const signature = await connection.sendRawTransaction(
  transaction, 
  { skipPreflight: true }
);

console.log(`https://explorer.solana.com/tx/${signature}?cluster=devnet`);
```

This doesn't answer your question but hopefully, it gets you nearer to the answer.

Comment: I am running from typescript like this. I'm submitting the transaction with the `.rpc()` fn.

I will try to convert it to your form

Comment: In that case, you can set skipPreflight to true in your provider like so:

import { setProvider } from "@project-serum/anchor";

const provider = new AnchorProvider(
        connection, 
        anchorWallet, 
        {
          skipPreflight: true,
        }
      );
      setProvider(provider);

Comment: Thanks! Finally some new information
`> Program returned error: "SBF program panicked"`

Comment: Are you getting a transaction signature now?

Comment: Yes! Now I can go see the failed transaction on the block explorer and was able to see the actual error logs. Thanks!